# When using vee-validate, A filed is under a scope.This.errors.first('field') does not work

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I want to validate a part first, and then the user will receive the mobile phone validation code, and then validate all when the user submits it. But I can't get the wrong information from this.errors.first('field') for the first time.

```
<template lang="html">
  <div>
    <form data-vv-scope="s">
        <input type="text" v-validate="'required'" data-vv-name="s1">
        <input type="text" v-validate="'required'" data-vv-name="s1">
        <button @click="vali" type="button">submit</button>
        <div @click="see">see</div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ErrorBag } from 'vee-validate';
export default {
  methods:{
    vali () {
        this.$validator.validateAll(["s1"]);
    },
    see () {
        console.log(this.errors.first("s1")) //can't get the wrong information
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `this.$validator.validateAll(["s1"]);` shouldn't it be `this.$validator.validate("s1");` ?

Comment: also try injecting `$validator` `
  inject: {
    $validator: '$validator',
  },`

Answer (score 0):

When a field has a scope, you need to reference it with that scope:

`this.errors.first("s.s1")`

Check out the code here: https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/examples/scopes.html